# How to find the 'concave outline' of a graph in 2D plane?

Tags: algorithms

I have a graph in 2D plane defined by some points and edges between them. Now is there a way (maybe an existing algorithm that I don't know of) to find the outline of this graph? The issue is that some vertices of the (possibly concave) outline polygon may not be the points in the original graph, but rather the intersection of two edges, so I'm not quite sure how to deal with it...

Thanks!

Niko

Comment: Please clarify. For instance, If the input consisted of the four vertices at $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ and the two diagonal edges between them, what would the "outline polygon" be? What if the input were a single edge? Or just two vertices and no edges? Or a square (4 edges, 4 verts) with one extra vertex that happens to lie exactly on an edge of the square?

Comment: It will just be the square. The graph should always be connected, and actually each vertex should have at least three neighbors. In the case of degeneracy it should be safe to ignore the extra points on the edge.

Comment: Yes the edges can intersect... sorry for the inaccurate use of terms.